# Show toast after a form submit

Tags: reactjs, forms, react-hooks, use-effect, react-toastify

I want to submit a form and I want to reload the current page so that form gets refreshed and after refreshing I want to show the Api response in toast. When I comment out event.preventDefault(), it doesn't show toast after the reload. And when I use event.preventDefault() and manually reload the page, the toast works fine! but I want it to be automatically refreshed and show toast. Here's my code,

```
    const handleAddUser = async (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    try {
      const result = await Http.post(apiEndPoint, {
        userRole: role,
        userEmail: userEmail,
        userPassword: userPassword,
        firstName: firstName,
        lastName: lastName,
        address: address,
      });
      localStorage.setItem("res", "success");
      localStorage.setItem("success", result.data);
      console.log("proper", props);
    } catch (ex) {
      localStorage.setItem("res", "err");
      localStorage.setItem("err", ex.response.data);
    }
  };
```

and here's my useEffect hook,

```
    useEffect(() => {
    const response = localStorage.getItem("res");
    const result = localStorage.getItem(response);
    if (response && response === "success") {
      toast.success(result);
      localStorage.removeItem("res");
    } else if (response && response === "err") {
      toast.error(result);
      localStorage.removeItem("res");
    }
  }, []);
```

Comment: Just put `window.location.reload();` before the `localStorage.setItem("res", "success");` and keep `event.preventDefault();` as it is.

Comment: Amazing, thanks it works now... I tried many times props.history.push() and window.location.reload() but the mistake was that i was trying after the line localStorage.setItem('res','success');

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**That is because if you remove `event.preventDefault()`, your page got reload before it has a chance to send a request and set to the localStorage**

A solution is to keep `event.preventDefault()` and put `window.location.reload()` at the end of your handler like so:

```
const handleAddUser = async (event) => {
  event.preventDefault();
  try {
    const result = await Http.post(apiEndPoint, {
      userRole: role,
      userEmail: userEmail,
      userPassword: userPassword,
      firstName: firstName,
      lastName: lastName,
      address: address,
    });
    localStorage.setItem("res", "success");
    localStorage.setItem("success", result.data);
    console.log("proper", props);
  } catch (ex) {
    localStorage.setItem("res", "err");
    localStorage.setItem("err", ex.response.data);
  }
  window.location.reload();
};
```

Comment: You could mark this answer as accept, if it helps and for others who need it.